# How to install PHP on Visual Studio Online / Codespaces

Tags: php, visual-studio, codespaces

Constant error for any and all versions of PHP - no installation candidate. I've ran apt-get update and upgrade / dist-upgrade and added the sury repo on a new codespace.

```
vsonline:~/workspace$ sudo apt-get install php
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package php is a virtual package provided by:
  php7.4 7.4.6-1+0~20200514.17+debian9~1.gbp0f509e [Not candidate version]
  php7.3 7.3.18-1+0~20200515.59+debian9~1.gbp12fa4f [Not candidate version]
  php7.2 7.2.31-1+0~20200514.41+debian9~1.gbpe2a56b [Not candidate version]
  php7.1 7.1.33-16+0~20200514.38+debian9~1.gbp1e5820 [Not candidate version]
  php7.0 7.0.33-29+0~20200514.36+debian9~1.gbp126f6f [Not candidate version]
  php5.6 5.6.40-29+0~20200514.35+debian9~1.gbpcc49a4 [Not candidate version]
  php7.3 7.3.14-1~deb10u1 [Not candidate version]
  uwsgi-plugin-php 2.0.17.1+8+0.0.3+b3 [Not candidate version]
  php7.3 7.3.11-1~deb10u1 [Not candidate version]
  php7.0 7.0.33-0+deb9u7 [Not candidate version]
  php7.0 7.0.33-0+deb9u6 [Not candidate version]

E: Package 'php' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: Try to install `php7.4` instead - i.e. explicitly saying which version you want.

Comment: This appears to be a linux package manager query, nothing to do with VS code specifically. Question would be more suitable on the super-user site

Comment: @MatsLindh exact same issue I'm afraid

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same headache, but I decided to do the manual installation

use:

```
wget https://www.php.net/distributions/php-7.4.9.tar.gz
#Or the version of your preference
```

Unpack and install

```
tar zxf php-x.x.x
cd ../php-x.x.x
./configure --enable-fpm --with-mysqli
make
sudo make install
```

Obtain and move configuration files to their correct locations

```
cp php.ini-development /usr/local/php/php.ini
cp /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf.default /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
cp sapi/fpm/php-fpm /usr/local/bin
```

Source: [official documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/install.unix.nginx.php)  [Links download php](https://www.php.net/downloads.php)

Or if you prefer to use Docker
I recommend the laradock that makes the job much easier.
I ended up using it, Doc is very easy [Laradock DOC](https://laradock.io/)

Comment: "Or if you prefer to use Docker" - just for PHP?

Comment: @MikeThrussell Yes, there is the laradock that makes the job a lot easier.
I ended up using it, Doc is very easy to [Laradock DOC](https://laradock.io/)